# Geodesics and potential function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesics

I try to assemble concepts of differential geometry for my own comprehension of the subject. I understand a manifold is a higher dimensional surface. It has a metric which perform inner product in the tangent space. A curve on the respective manifold has a  covariant derivative, which remains on the tangent bundle. A geodesic is a manner to comprehend straight lines on a manifold. They might be closed like on a sphere. They are the main tool of physicists to comprehend the universe through the lagrangian and hamiltonian framework. On the lagrangian framework, there is a kinetic $K = g_{ij} \dot{x}_i \dot{x}_j$ and potential $U = V(x)$ energies which computes the lagrangian $L = K - U$. The ausence of potential energy coincide with the geodesic equation. The Einstein notation is in force here.

In mathematical terms, I do not comprehend the role of the potential or dissipative term on the geodesic equation and further explanations on similar manner as I will explain shortly.

As far I comprehend, the geodesic statement is: given two points A and B, the geodesic which binds both points on a simply connected non-compact smooth manifold is the solution to the boundary value problem of former equation below.

The same statement but for the latter equation entertains other interpretation, no longer a geodesic at strict sense. I comprehend from physical perspective that given the manifold endowed by a metric, the second and third are relative to the actuation  of forces on the motion particle. But for this, one defines the particle, which is merely an abstract conception, a trick to better comprehend intuitively.

\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}^j + \Gamma^j_{i k} \dot{x}^i \dot{x}^k = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}^j + \Gamma^j_{i k} \dot{x}^i \dot{x}^k + g^{ji} \frac{\partial V}{\partial x^i} = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}^j + \Gamma^j_{i k} \dot{x}^i \dot{x}^k + g^{ji} \frac{\partial V}{\partial x^i} + g^{ji} \frac{\partial R}{\partial \dot{x}^i} = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: What is your question here? From the looks of it, $R$ is just another potential term just like $V$, that could be absorbed into it.

Comment: The questions are: What is the geodesic equation when the boudary values are not points A and B but initial position and velocity? What is the influence of the potential term on the geodesic equation when employed as a Point A B condition? The same for with Rayleigh i.e . dissipative function?

Comment: The role of those terms is the same as their role in Newtonian classical mechanics, where the Riemannian manifold is flat Euclidean space. So you should ask a physicist or look in a classical mechanics textbook to see how such terms appear. Your questions have no mathematical answer, only an answer in physical intuition.

Comment: Why doesn't it have a mathematical answer? The physical statement relies on the mathematical toolset to perform its calculation.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto I'm not sure what the question actually is.  If I re-interpret it as asking for a geometrical set-up to discuss lagrangian/hamiltonian systems with potentials, then I have two comments: (1) you may be able to rewrite the equation as a geodesic equatoin for an affine connection which is not necessarily metric (cf. Newton-Cartan theory) and (2) you may be able to view it as a geodesic equation in an auxiliary space relative to the Levi-Civita connection (cf. the Eisenhart lift).

Comment: I'm also not sure I really understand the issue, but my reaction is that the geodesic equation and its generalizations on the one side, and the boundary conditions on the other side are separate ingredients. Ideally, you would solve the geodesic equation in general, leaving you with integration constants, and then you fix the integration constants to the boundary data, in whatever way they're given. So the geodesic equation, and additional potential, etc. terms don't depend on the form of the boundary data, these are separate pieces of information. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Perhaps you could revise what you wrote and be more specific and precise about what you want to know? I would observe, however, if there is a non constant potential, then there is a force acting on the particle’s motion and therefore the path with least energy is no longer a geodesic. The second equation can be viewed geometrically as saying something about the curvature of the path.

Comment: Does the last paragraph clarify my intentions regarding my doubt? I enjoy José Figueroa's answer. Michael provides some intuition, but it lacks rigor. Deane, R regards the Rayleigh function and not the curvature notation.

Comment: I was referring to the second equation, which has no $R$.